# Is it possible to add an additional board on Arduino Web Editor (create.arduino.cc)?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using a board that can be programmed via Arduino IDE (a NodeMCU with ESP8266) and I've configured the Windows client successfully. I've added an additional board through "Preferences" menu by specifying [its configuration url](http://arduino.esp8266.com/versions/2.4.0/package_esp8266com_index.json), following manufacturer's directions.

Now, I'm quite happy with the web editor, the one at [create.arduino.cc](https://create.arduino.cc), and I'd like to use it with this board too. Is there any way to configure additional boards?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

The web editor is completely closed. It's a service run by Arduino, and as such it will only support Arduino's own boards.

Two reasons:

1. Why should they spend the time, effort and money adding support for other people's products?
2. It adds value to their products to encourage you to use real Ardiuno hardware.

Business is business, after all.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. The border is a bit blurred to me, sorry: seeing that feature on the client IDE made me wonder if the same was available on the web counterpart.

Comment: Here's a statement from an Arduino employee to the contrary: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=361376.msg2741262#msg2741262 *"we will support 3rd party HW in the future"*. On the other hand that statement was made over 1.5 years ago. I think there are security challenges to this since they will need to allow 3rd party applications to run on their server. I also wouldn't say "completely closed" since there are open source components but certainly a lot of it is closed. Interestingly there is another comment in that thread indicating there was a consideration of making it open.